# How to exist from fscanf loop?

Tags: c

I want to exist from loop when there no more data to read.
I had try !feof(fp), EOF, but it loop infinitely. 
If i change to fscanf(fp, str,  &str) == 1, it can't read anything.
Here is the code:

```
void readFile(){

    FILE *fp;   
    int i=0, j=1;   
    int* arr;
    char str[45];


    fp = fopen("c:\\Defuzzification.txt","r"); // read mode

    if (fp == NULL) {       
        perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }



    arr = (int*)calloc(SIZE, sizeof(int));

    while( fscanf(fp, "The different between frame %d and %d :%d",  &i, &j, arr)  == 1 ){
        fscanf(fp, "The different between frame %d and %d :%d",  &i, &j, arr);
        printf("Display The different between frame %d and %d :%d\n",  i, j, *arr);
        i++;
        j++;    
    }

    fclose(fp); 
}
```

while(fscanf(fp, "The different between frame %d and %d :%d",  &i, &j, arr) != EOF) =>> loop infinite

while( fscanf(fp, "The different between frame %d and %d :%d",  &i, &j, arr)  == 1 ) =>> read nothing

input data:

```
The different between frame 0 and 1 :80
The different between frame 1 and 2 :58.18
The different between frame 2 and 3 :77.59
The different between frame 3 and 4 :71.24
The different between frame 4 and 5 :68.46
The different between frame 5 and 6 :75.81
The different between frame 6 and 7 :41.35
```

Comment: not a good way but I use to do while(fscanf(fp,"%s",str)!=EOF)

Comment: using `fscanf(fp, str, &str)` will cause undefined behaviour , you are overwriting your string pointer with the input you just read

Comment: @sasha that only works for `%s` ; if OP is scanning other things then the matching against a positive number is better

Comment: @user2301281 your post is very unclear; please post the actual code you have tried so far (make sure it compiles before posting)

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: sorry for the poor qs. Actually I want to scan the int from file & store it into array. But I don't know how to exist from loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following statement, `fscanf` will return 3 if all the input operations are successful.

```
while( fscanf(fp, "The different between frame %d and %d :%d",  &i, &j, arr)  == 1 ){
```

Change it to:

```
while( fscanf(fp, "The different between frame %d and %d :%d",  &i, &j, arr)  == 3 ){
```

Another thing... You have numbers `80`, `58.18`, etc. These are floating point numbers not integral number. Shouldn't you be using a floating point format and read it to a floating point variable?

```
float number;
while( fscanf(fp, "The different between frame %d and %d :%f",  &i, &j, &number)  == 3 ){
```

**Update**

You need to make the following changes:

1. In the format string to `fscaf`, put a space as the first character. This will skip zero or more white spaces, including newline characters.
2. Use a floating point number to read the last data. Otherwise, the fractional part of the number gets left behind in the input stream and the subsequent read operation fails.
3. You need to compare the return value of `fscanf` in the conditional of the `while` statement to `3`. `fscanf` will return `3` if it is able to successfully read all the three pieces of data.

Using the following block of code for reading the data works for me:

```
float number;
while( fscanf(fp, " The different between frame %d and %d :%f",  &i, &j, &number)  == 3 ){
    fscanf(fp, " The different between frame %d and %d :%f",  &i, &j, &number);
    printf("Display The different between frame %d and %d :%f\n",  i, j, number);
    i++;
    j++;    
}
```

Comment: I change to 3 but it only read the 1st data. Btw, why change to 3?

Comment: when i change it to float, the value read become zero. EDIT: float* arr, arr = (float*)calloc(SIZE, sizeof(float));

Comment: I don't understand the update 1. Is it become =>>
while(fscanf(fp, " The different between frame %d and %d :%d", &i, &j, arr) == 3) ??
But the output just read two row of data then stop.

Comment: @user2301281, Not sure what you did. See working code at http://ideone.com/dnrPPk.

Comment: It seem work well for float. But if i want to store the data into array then it have problem @@. How to store in array?

Comment: & the output you shown will skip the 1st row of data.

Comment: It doesn't skip the first row of data. It just prints every second row since you have two `fscanf` statements but only one `printf` statement.